# KSH: constraint the number of thread that can run at one time

Tags: linux, bash, concurrency, ksh, sh

I have a script that loop and each iteration invoke a thread that run in a background like below

`xn_run_process.sh`

```
...
for each in `ls ${INPUT_DIR}/MDX*.txt`
do
      java -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -cp ${CLASSPATH} com.wf.xn.etcc.Main -config=${CONFIG_FILE}
      ...
      for SCALE_PDF in `ls ${PROCESS_DIR}/*.pdf`
      do
          OUTPUT_AFP=${OUTPUT_DIR}/`basename ${SCALE_PDF}`
          OUTPUT_AFP=`print ${OUTPUT_AFP} | sed s/pdf/afp/g`
          ${PROJ_DIR}/myscript.sh -i ${SCALE_PDF} -o ${OUTPUT_AFP} &
          sleep 30
      done
done
```

When I did this, I only think that it will be only 5 threads of `myscript.sh` be concurrently executed at one time, however things change, and this list execute 30 threads, each does quite heavy process. How do I constraint the number of concurrent processes to 5?

Answer (score 1):

While this is possible in pure shell scripting, the easiest approach would be using a parallelization tool like GNU parallel or GNU make. Makefile example:

```
SOURCES = ${SOME_LIST}
STAMPS = $(SOME_LIST:=.did-run-stamp)

all : $(STAMPS)

%.did-run-stamp : %
    /full/path/myscript.sh -f $<
```

and then calling make as `make -j 5`.

Comment: hi do you call `make -j 5` inside the script or on the shell? and dont you have to put a `target` for the `make`?

Comment: can you also explain a bit about `did-run-stamp`, please?

Comment: Inside the shell, in the directory where the shown file is the `Makefile`. Make by default uses the first target (`all` by convention), and the `did-run-stamp` is just a dummy file name that does not already exist and acts as a target for make. If you would use the original filenames, make would just check that all files are present and succeed without action.

Comment: I have updated some codes, with two more questions, will you please show me? Thank you so much

Comment: @HarryPham: Sorry, but I feel I'm drifting too far from advice-giving to code-writing here. My post is (of course, like every other) open for editing, if there is someone who feels more motivated. This thing should be pretty straigt-forward with make. If you really can't get forward, get a nice `make` tutorial; `info make` is a good start.

Comment: The more I look into this `make`, its purpose is more to compile program rather than execute other script at run-time. Thanks though.

Comment: @HarryPham: Yeah, make's original purpose is a little different, but run control is not far away from compilation control. `GNU parallel` has its focus more on parallel execution.

Answer (score 1):

Use GNU Parallel (adjust -j as you see fit. Remove it if you want # of CPUs):

```
for each in `ls ${INPUT_DIR}/MDX*.txt`
do
      java -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -cp ${CLASSPATH} com.wf.xn.etcc.Main -config=${CONFIG_FILE}
      ...
      for SCALE_PDF in `ls ${PROCESS_DIR}/*.pdf`
      do
          OUTPUT_AFP=${OUTPUT_DIR}/`basename ${SCALE_PDF}`
          OUTPUT_AFP=`print ${OUTPUT_AFP} | sed s/pdf/afp/g`
          sem --id myid -j 5 ${PROJ_DIR}/myscript.sh -i ${SCALE_PDF} -o ${OUTPUT_AFP}
      done
done
sem --wait --id myid
```

`sem` is part of GNU Parallel.

This will keep 5 jobs running until there is only 5 jobs left. Then it will allow your java to run while finishing the last 5. The `sem --wait` will wait until the last 5 are finished, too.

Alternatively:

```
for each ...
   java ...
   ...
   ls ${PROCESS_DIR}/*.pdf |
   parallel -j 5 ${PROJ_DIR}/myscript.sh -i {} -o ${OUTPUT_DIR}/{/.}.afp
done
```

This will run 5 jobs in parallel and only let java run when all the jobs are finished.

Alternatively you can use the queue trick described in GNU Parallel's man page: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example__gnu_parallel_as_queue_system_batch_manager

```
echo >jobqueue; tail -f jobqueue | parallel -j5 &
for each ...
   ...
   ls ${PROCESS_DIR}/*.pdf |
   parallel echo ${PROJ_DIR}/myscript.sh -i {} -o ${OUTPUT_DIR}/{/.}.afp >> jobqueue
done
echo killall -TERM parallel >> jobqueue
wait
```

This will run java, then add jobs to be run to a queue. After adding jobs java will be run immediately. At all time 5 jobs will be run from the queue until the queue is empty.

You can install GNU Parallel simply by:

```
wget http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/src/parallel
chmod 755 parallel
cp parallel sem
```

Watch the intro videos to learn more: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1 and walk through the tutorial (man parallel_tutorial). You command line with love you for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have *ksh93* check if *JOBMAX* is available:

> JOBMAX
>
> ```
> This variable defines the maximum number running background
> jobs that can run at a time. When this limit is reached, the
> shell will wait for a job to complete before staring a new job.
> ```